# Potentials in Feynman path integral II

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am still working on the Feynman path integral, more specifically on the case of a free particle with an infinite potential wall, i.e. the quantum system defined by the Hamiltonian

$$H_1 = \frac{\mathbf{P}^2}{2m} + V(\mathbf{Q})$$

where $V(\mathbf{Q})$ is the potential defined by

$$
V(\mathbf{Q})=\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
\infty, & \mathbf{Q} \leq b \\
0, & \mathbf{Q}>b. \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

It is clear that a general solution for the free particle case is given by
$$\psi_E(q) = A_1 e^{i\frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{\hbar}q} + A_2 e^{-i\frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{\hbar}q}.$$
Using the fact that $\psi_E(0)=0$ I get that $A_2=-A_1$ so the general solution is
$$A \sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{\hbar}q\right) = A \sin(kq)$$
where $k$ is defined as
$$k=\frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{\hbar}.$$
The problem I have is the calculation of the constant $A$. In some references they say this constant should be 
$$A = \sqrt{\frac{2m}{\pi\hbar^2 k}}$$
and in other references I find $A=2$ or $A=-2i$,...

Could you please help me to understand that point ? Thanks.

Comment: The Hamiltonian is Euclidean, so the normalising factor is $\sqrt{\frac{2i\pi\hbar}{Nm}}$, . Does that clear the confusion? .

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't know what a Euclidean Hamiltonian is, and what $N$ is. The dimension of the space ?

Comment: No, not the dimension of the space! Maybe I should have been more clear. $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sqrt{\frac{2i\pi\hbar}{Nm}}$ is the infinitesimal reciprocal of the  normalising factor of the phase, and  a Euclidean Hamiltonian just means that it takes the form $\frac{p^2}{2m}+U$.

Comment: Ok, but this constant comes after in the calculation. The constant $A$ coming from the eigenfunctions and your constant coming from the path integral are not the same thing, I guess.

Comment: Actually, I got this reference from a previous post (reference [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.3674)) and I am trying to understand it.

Comment: Oh, now that I see that statement about $\sin q$...

Comment: @Ludo : First, it is $\psi_E(b)=0$ and not $\psi_E(0)=0$. Second, your $\psi_E(q)$ is not square-integrable, so why do you care about the constant ?

Comment: @Trimok : Thanks for the correction. I care about it because the author does in the reference you provided me. I am just trying to understand the whole calculation, and this constant is of importance in it.

Comment: Probably $A$ becomes $2$ or $-2i$ in the specific situations that each of the "other sources" mention?

Comment: When the function is not square integrable, you typically choose A so that the inner product of two levels (E and E') is the delta function. It's completely arbitrary, but it's probably what the authors were doing.